# firebase google or query support or any alternative solution

Tags: ios, firebase, kinvey, mbaas, nosql

We have just started exploring firebase for our new app. The app basically needs chat between users and Group chat.

For the chat application we are creating: **MessageThread(id, User:userA, User:userB, UserGroup:group, Array:deletedBy, ...)**

The main problem is firebase doesn't support OR queries and IN queries, which I need in my use-case. For example:

Dummy query to access user's conversations list:
**fetch MessageThread(s) where (currentUser.id==userA.id) OR (currentUser.id==userB.id) OR (currentUser.id IN group.members)**

I am missing something to understand Firebase? What is the other alternative way to design our database to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In NoSQL you will have to model the data for the way your app wants to use it. So if you need a list of the conversations that the user is part of, you should keep that list in your database:

```
/conversationMessages
    $conversationId
        $messageId
            text: "Hello world"
            sender: "uid of sender"
            name: "name of sender"
/userConversations
   $uid
     $conversationId1: true
     $conversationId2: true
```

With this you can easily look up the list of conversations that each user is a part of and then load the messages for one of them. You'll probably also want to keep a separate list of the metadata for each conversation:

```
/conversationMetadata
    $conversationId
        lastUpdated: timestamp (set with ServerValue.TIMESTAMP)
        title: "name of our chat room"
```

That way you can show the list of conversations for a user by loading their conversation ids and then loading the metadata of each conversation:

```
var ref = database.ref().child("userConversations").child(auth.uid);
ref.on('child_added', function(conversationKey) {
    var conversationRef = database.ref().child("conversationMetadata").child(conversationKey.key);
    conversationRef.once('value', function(metadataSnapshot) {
      console.log(metadataSnapshot.val());
    });
});
```

Trying to map SQL knowledge onto a NoSQL database leads to a difficult learning experience. I highly recommend reading the [relevant section of the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data) and this [article about NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: Thank you, one more question: Is there any support of making references in firebase? For example: I want to save user's object in conversation, so that I can show user's name and photo on the conversation list screen.

Comment: There are no managed foreign key references. But it's very common to have (unmanaged) references. See the section of the documentation on [creating data that scales](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout).

Comment: In my senerio, I have group/user chat and chat name & image is fetched from that group/user And I can't denormalize it because user has the option to change it anytime. So from your mentioned approach, I can have a table /conversationMetadata where I will a reference of user/group. Now the problem is for fetching a conversation list (as explained in your mentioned above code): First I am fetching userConversations then I am fetching conversationMetadata for every conversation and then I need to fetch userData or groupData (to get name/image). Don't u think it will be too slow? Please help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786